# Dynamic SQL in Model or Controller

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I know all logic etc should go in the controller, but I have an SQL statement where some parts of it are determined by another function's return value.

In my model:

```
    $cols = 'products.id, name, currencies.symbol, basePrice';
    $m = new AuthController();
    if($m->moduleExists('Sales'))
    {
      $cols .= 'lastSold';
    }
```

Or in my controller and have the SQL passed to the model as a parameter?

```
    $cols = 'products.id, name, currencies.symbol, basePrice';
    if($this->moduleExists('Sales'))
    {
      $cols .= 'lastSold';
    }
```

Comment: There should be almost **no** logic in the controller. And definitely no SQL. I don't think that you grasp even the basic responsibilities for each part of MVC triad.

Comment: @tereško you are thinking only of controller in terms of your understanding of MVC. Controllers do have logic. You can have controllers with ui logic (MVP), business logic per use case, DAO controllers with anemic models that belong to the model. All of these controllers have logic. Which are the ones you are referring to that do not have logic?

Comment: @teresko layered architecture is not achieved only with MVC, to name a few there are also  HMVC, MVA, MVP, MVVM . The user did not mention MVC, although i certainly do not agree with your comment.

Comment: The post was tagged "MVC", and not "my very code".

Comment: @tereško For the self-proclaimed authority on MVC, you provide very little useful input with regard to my question =p.

Comment: Lets see ... I told you what you were doing wrong and told you what you need to research. Instead you completely ignored it and accepted "answer" that is **completely wrong**. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr; version**

Having in mind the separation of concerns and decoupling, code related to persistence optimally should not contain business logic related to sub modules of the specific system *(whether that logic belongs in controllers of the Model part, of MVC, or the Controller part, or any other part the programmer has introduced to the system)*. Access from the persistence layer to business logic should be avoided to maintain decoupling, the other way around business logic accessing the persistence layer should be preferred.

**Justification**

In your model you should place code that is not relevant to what is shown to your views i.e. whether a module exists or not or whether authorised to have such a module. The code in your model should be useable by your sub systems, other systems, anything independent of your views or even business logic related to specific use cases. It should have logic related to the scope of the system. Although authorisation seems to have system scope this should be handled with extra care, since it may lead to brittle design. It is more flexible to have it at the controller level. Imagine trying to support multiple techniques of authorisation.

Depending on authorisation or view criteria to modify queries will not maintain a stable independent model.

So yes it should go in your controller.

The controller whether it is a controller related to the view or specific business logic (use case related or system related i.e. authorization controller) now could have the authorization criteria which change the query and in the future some other criteria may come up that are related to specific use case, or sub system domain. This means that the controller could change and also you will have the ability to even introduce different controllers accessing the same model with a specific way.

**Implementation**

There are plenty of approaches regarding your issue. Such as,

- retrieve a full version of your data i.e. all columns, from your persistence layer and have your controller decide what to show based on logic i.e. authorization of user
- have more than one queries in your persistence layer independent from your other logic i.e. queryProducts, queryProductsWithTotals, queryProductsWithLastSoldDate, then have your business logic controllers decide which to call
- create a generic function in persistence layer, accepting cols (non magic values if possible) in order to parametrize what can be viewed based on logic that other controllers have and call this function accordingly
- in general it is best to avoid placing sql queries in different places, since the maintenance becomes difficult. However there might be cases that this could happen and strongly depends on the design of the system i.e. business controllers with custom queries per use case that call the persistence layer in order to execute.